# db design - sign in with third party serivces (facebook connect, etc.)

Tags: database-design, facebook

What are from your opinions the best solution for a db schema when implementing e.g. facebook connect?

When I did some research, I found a suggestion to separate the login information (fb_id, ...) from the account information (e.g. firstname, surname, ...):
http://facebook-developer.net/2008/08/05/optimize-your-database-tables-for-facebook-connect/

The proposed solution of this article are three tables

CREATE TABLE `accounts` (
`id` int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
`name` text,
`email` text,
PRIMARY KEY `id` (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `users` (
`username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`password` text,
`account_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY `username` (`username`)
);

CREATE TABLE `facebook_users` (
`fb_uid` bigint(11) default NULL,
`email_hash` varchar(64) default NULL,
`account_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY `fb_uid` (`fb_uid`)
);

I don't see a clear argument why one could not just store all the data in one table.

table users (
  user_id,
  username,
  email,
  fb_id,
  email_hash,
  ...
)

A person usually has only one facebook account, so I don't see any problems with redundancy.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

For effectiveness, using a single table to persist all of the data is correct. And you just need to add a new column when adding another login service.

The performance, however, is worse than seperated tables if you want to know whether a user has facebook account. The performance of login is worse as well because database need to fetch the whole record for "email_hash".

The list of users' data, on the other hand, has better performance in design of single table because you don't have to join tables for such report.